# Google Apps Script - Read data from gmail specific label returns messages from all labels

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-sheets-api

There are 2 user defined labels in my gmail named x & y. I need to retrieve the messages present in that specific label, but am getting the data from all the labels.

I need Msg body, label and date received and update it in spreadsheet

Following is my code:

---

```
  var ulables = GmailApp.getUserLabels();
  for(var x=0; x < ulables.length; x++){ 
    var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(ulables[x].getName()).getThreads();

    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {    
      var messages = threads[i].getMessages();      
      var label = ulables[x].getName();     
      for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {        
        var msg     = messages[m].getBody();
        var cmsg    = convertHtmlToText(msg);

        var subject = messages[m].getSubject();
        if(subject == reqSub){
          var recDate = Utilities.formatDate(messages[m].getDate(),"GMT","MM/dd/yyyy");
          if(isDateInRange(recDate, startDate, endDate)){

            var arr =[recDate,label,cmsg];
            mailSheet.getRange(++lastRow, 1,1,3).setValues([arr]).activate();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

---

Ex:- Label x has 10 emails
     Label y has 10 emails
     Inbox has 50 emails

For each label, am getting 60 emails which is the problem, but I expect 10,10,50 emails.

Have been struggling it from last 2 days, but not succeeded. Please help me. Thanks a ton in advance.

---

Please let me know the details, have been waiting for it from last one week. Is there any way getting messages without using threads?

Comment: Have you considered the fact that threads not in inbox (eg. sent) can also have the same labels.

Comment: Yes, I checked there are no emails in sent, starred, important.

Comment: You could probably print out the subject line for each message / thread and then you'll have a clue of why thats happening

Comment: My problem here's, wanted to find out all the emails with the same subject across the labels.